can I trust compiler to avoid passing unused function parameters
I am writing error-handling code at many places, which typically has the form
    if (!condition)
        errorHandler(info);

here errorHandler is a function and info is in practice more than one parameter (e.g. a message in two parts, plus a line number, or whatever).
To streamline the code I write a function called runtimeAssert which goes like this:
    void runtimeAssert(bool condition, const string& msg, [... other info ...])
    {
       if (condition) return;

       ... here put the error handling code ...
    }

Then when I want to check for errors I can replace the first snippet above with
runtimeAssert(condition, msg, [... other info ...]);


I would like to ask whether the compiler can be trusted not to bother passing the parameters to runtimeAssert in the case where the condition is true. (Better still, I hope the compiler would not even generate a function call). This is simply about saving a bit of time when the program runs.
Follow-up question: If the compiler will typically optimise as I want, then is the above a good way to write code? And if the compiler will not be as intelligent as I wish, then should I use a macro?
(Note, this is not about debugging code, it is about efficiency of finished code.)
Obviously both versions work. It's not very easy for me to do a speed test.

This looks like a C++ question. Please update the tags to reflect this. Also, there is a macros tag but no C++ macros included in the question

Added C++ tag (macros tag left in because the question includes a question about use of macros.)

The call sites of runtimeAssert must evaluate all arguments and initialize all parameters. The compiler might remove some of this work if it can prove that the parameters are unused and there are no side-effects in the argument evaluations. Usually, this is impossible. The cases where this is possible are the exception. At a minimum runtimeAssert must be an inline function, so that the compiler can see through the call.
